# Дизайн приложения в эмуляторе отличается от превью

Tags: java, android

Создал дизайн активности. Запустил дабы проверить все. Оказалось, что дизайн на превью отличается от самого дизайна в эмуляторе (Ужасный градиент и кнопки налезают друг на друга).

[image: Превью]

[image: Эмулятор]

Код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sign_in_gradient_bar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Введите данные"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Пароль"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_Button_Login"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Войти"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainActivity_Button_Register"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Зарегистрироваться"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас статические размеры кнопок. Возможно, в Андроид Студио у Вас большой размер экрана, а при эмуляции - маленький, а т.к. размеры статические, то резльтат будет такой, как у Вас. И зачем делать два одинаковые лаяуты ? Делали бы в главном.
Вообще, сделайте для этих 2ух кнопок LinearLayout, и android:layout_width сделайте равным 0 для каждой кнопки. Также добавьте новый параметр weight, для логин кнопки установите значение 1, а для регистрации 2.

Comment: Я делал такое же в другом проекте, но там все работало хорошо, не знаю, что делать

Comment: Сделайте LinearLayout и вставьте туда эти две кнопки, затем проделайте то, что написал выше.

Comment: А, все, разобрался, благодарю за помощь!